# Using html2canvas with Sinatra and Raphael

Tags: javascript, sinatra, raphael, screenshot, html2canvas

I'm trying to use html2canvas to take a screenshot of a page hosted with Sinatra. It's working except for the fact none of the jpgs on it are being copied. The jpgs have drag and drop capability implemented with raphael. Here's a screenshot with the original image on top and the copied image on the bottom. [image]

Here's the code, taken from the html2canvas documentation:

```
function appendScreenshot(){
  html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

}

The cards are represented as rectangle objects on a raphael canvas.

```
main_canvas = Raphael('main_canvas', canvas_width, canvas_height),

//this line is repeated several times to create different card objects that can 
//be dragged around, filled with images titled "image1.jpg", image2.jpg", etc.
cards[card_name] = main_canvas.rect(10, 10, 80, 80).attr('fill', 'url(images/resized/image' + card_name + '.jpg)');
```

How can I get it to correctly take a screenshot of the page?